# AWS Organizations: root is not authorized to perform: route53:ListHostedZones

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am new to using AWS Organizations, and there I have this issue: I created an account (let's call it test@example.com), and in the "Organize accounts" tab, that account is under 'Root -> dev'.

I created the policy "route53 full access":

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1535536356000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "route53:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I associated the policy with both the account test@example.com and the 'dev' organizational unit, however in the AWS console of the test@example.com I am getting these errors:

```
root is not authorized to perform: route53:ListHostedZones with an explicit deny
```

Only if I set the policy to the 'Root' (above the dev), I can access the route53 in the AWS console of test@sample.com

Is this the way that it is suppose to work?